# Set GtkButton width

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, gtk3

I have a problem to set the width of GtkButton(s). When I use `gtk_widget_set_size_request(button, width, height)` with `width = 40` and `height = 40`, I have a wrong width and a good height. See it :

[image: Here is the problem :]

My code :

```
// On sépare les panneaux :
GtkWidget* commands_drawing_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
GtkWidget* buttons_tabpanel_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

// On met tout sur le container
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(container), buttons_tabpanel_box);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(container), commands_drawing_box);

// Boutons
GtkWidget* buttons_grid = gtk_grid_new();
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(buttons_tabpanel_box), buttons_grid, TRUE, TRUE, 1);

// Bouton "Nouveau dessin"
GtkWidget* btn_new_drawing_button_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
GtkWidget* btn_new_drawing = gtk_button_new();
GtkWidget* btn_new_drawing_image = gtk_image_new_from_file("D:\\Dev\\Icones_32px\\32_newdocument.png");
gtk_button_set_image(GTK_BUTTON(btn_new_drawing), btn_new_drawing_image);
gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(buttons_grid), btn_new_drawing_button_box, 0, 0, 1, 1);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(btn_new_drawing_button_box), btn_new_drawing);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(btn_new_drawing, 40, 40);
```

And I don't want to use Glade.

Can you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible cases as to why your button width is wrong is maybe due to the width of the image.The image is greater than 40. in this case the image won't be resized and the button will wrap around the image.

in your code your using GtkButtonBox which make the button layout homogeneous.(as an alternative you could use gtkbox) 
if you remove that then your code is working fine.

but if you have to use the button-box. then try changing the widget properties. (https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButtonBox.html#GtkButtonBox--s-child-min-height)

inside the button padding and min-height will be set to remove those you have to use css

```
button {
min-width:0px;
padding:0px;
border:0px;
}
```

To help in your debugging try using gtk-debugger (https://askubuntu.com/questions/597259/how-do-i-open-gtk-inspector)

Comment: Images are 32x32 and buttons request are 40x40. It's also the case with button with text

Comment: if possible could you share a working code..from your above code resizing the image seems to be working for me..

Comment: Source code can be found here [link](https://github.com/TW2/Feuille/tree/master/src/source_v2.3.2_C%2B%2B_MSVC_GTK3). Images are loaded manually so you have to modify the code to see them.